# Why is $ab = cd$ in this triangle?

Tags: triangles

[image: pythagoras reciprocal theorem lema]

I'm trying to understand the proof of the reciprocal Pythagorean theorem, but it seems to depend on the fact that $ab = cd$ in the picture above, but I cannot see why.  Assuming the result, I can then apply Pythagoras getting $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ which implies $1/b^2 + 1/a^2 = c^2/(a^2b^2)$ which implies $1/b^2 + 1/a^2 = c^2/(c^2d^2)$ which implies $1/b^2 + 1/a^2 = c^2/(c^2d^2)$ ending up with $1/b^2 + 1/a^2 = 1/d^2$, as desired.  (So I'm missing only why $ab = cd$.)

Comment: Consider the area in two different ways, with two different bases.

Comment: This is necessary for the condition that the triangle has a right angle. In this case , both $ab$ and $cd$ are half of the area of the triangle.

Comment: It's the area of a rectangle spanned by c and d. This area is equal to the span of the parallelogram spanned by a and b

Comment: @Peter You mean they are twice the triangle area.

Comment: @coffeemath Oh, of course ! Humiliating ...

Comment: Oh, I finally see it.  I can consider the big triangle's area in two different ways:  one where $b$ is the height and $a$ is the base --- so I get its area equal to $ab/2$ --- and the other where $d$ is the height and $c$ is the base --- so I get $cd/2$.  Equating both, I get $ab = cd$.  Phew.  Simple, huh?  I had not seen it, despite the hint in the image.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the angle between $a$ and $c$ be $\alpha$. Note that $\sin(\alpha)=\cos(90^\circ-\alpha)$.

Therefore $\sin(\alpha)=\frac{d}{a}$, so $a=\frac{d}{sin(\alpha)}$.

Similarly, $\cos(90^\circ-\alpha)=\sin(\alpha)=\frac{b}{c}$, so $b=c\sin(\alpha)$.

Therefore $ab=cd$.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative proof!

Comment: The observation that $\cos(90 - \alpha) = \sin(\alpha)$ is not needed.  We can just use the two perspectives of the $\sin(\alpha)$ and make the connection as you did.  My two cents.